# Show minimum price for WooCommerce variable products (Version 2.5.5)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I am using the latest version of WooCommerce-2.5.5. But, it showing the maximum price for the variable product in shop and single product page (https://bookyoga.com.au/flametreeyoga/all-passes/, https://bookyoga.com.au/flametreeyoga/product/two-classes-per-week/). But I want to show the minimum price for the variable product.

I have tried many hooks for showing the minimum price but not working (like https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202794676-Showing-only-1-price-for-variable-product and so many hooks). 
I have tried WooCommerce 2.1 variation price, revert to 2.0 format (https://gist.github.com/kloon/8981075) which also not working.

Can anyone please help me to solve the problem for showing the minimum price for the variable products instead of maximum price.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for that :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'get_min_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'get_min_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

function get_min_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
    $min_variation_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min');
    return wc_price($min_variation_price);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have tried this hook before but not working.

Comment: Did you try my code at least ? is there any other plgins that might override this ? what theme are you using ?

Comment: Yes, I have used it again, but not working. The theme name is "For The Cause" provided by the woothemes (https://www.woothemes.com/products/for-the-cause/). I think there is no other plugin for override this.
FYI- We are using Subscriptio - WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/subscriptio-woocommerce-subscriptions/8754068) for subscription the products.

Comment: can you please tell me where do you put these hooks ? is it in a plugin or in functions.php ? does the hooks actually run ? for debuging purpose : put a die('Works'); inside the get_min_variation_price_format function and sahre the output.

Comment: I have used it in theme functions.php. Also the die('Works'); works properly inside the function get_min_variation_price_format. Please see the screenshot http://imgur.com/KnplKfC

Comment: Working perfect in my case too.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code in your theme's functions.php ( Tested and Verified )

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
 $price = '';
 $price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());
 return $price;
}
```